# Asp:Button not firing in bootstrap Tab Panes

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have set a bootstrap tab pane, within this tab pane there is a form, on asp:Button press the code will not execute.

I know the code works as when not in the tab pane it works every time.
But its for a user control page and would be better to provide function within the tab panes.

This is for all buttons within the tab pane.
if one gets solved then the method to repair others is made!

Here is the HTML markup:

```
        <div class="tab-content col-lg-10">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="pane1">
                    <%--Content goes in here, so tables, and whatever else--%>
                    <h3>My Bookings</h3>
                    <div class="container">
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="dgBookingView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="myBookings" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" UseAccessibleHeader="True">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingID" HeaderText="Booking #" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="BookingID" />


                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FilmName" HeaderText="Movie" SortExpression="FilmName" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Requirements" HeaderText="Requirements" SortExpression="Requirements" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Showtime" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Showtime" DataFormatString="{0:t}" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShowDate" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="ShowDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="myBookings" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Booking.BookingID, Booking.CustomerFK, Booking.AuditorumFK, Booking.Requirements, Film.FilmName, Showtime.Showtime, Showtime.ShowDate, Showtime.AuditoriumID, Customers.UserNameFK FROM (((((Booking INNER JOIN Seat ON Booking.BookingID = Seat.BookingFK) INNER JOIN Auditorium ON Seat.AuditoriumFK = Auditorium.AuditoriumID) INNER JOIN Showtime ON Auditorium.AuditoriumID = Showtime.AuditoriumID) INNER JOIN Film ON Showtime.FilmFK = Film.FilmID) INNER JOIN Customers ON Booking.CustomerFK = Customers.CustomerID)
WHERE([Customers.UserNameFK] = ? )">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:SessionParameter
                                    Name="userNamePa"
                                    SessionField="userName"
                                    DefaultValue="userName" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>


                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Specify any Special Requirements</h3>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Booking #</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtBookingID"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <h4>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfUserNameValid" ControlToValidate="txtBookingID" runat="server"
                                            ErrorMessage="Enter a Booking Number" CssClass="label label-danger">
                                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Extra Requirements</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRequirements" class="form-control" Rows="5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Make Change" ID="btnRequirements" OnClick="btnRequirements_OnClick" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="pane2" runat="server">
                    <%--Change User Password START--%>
                    <h3>Change Password</h3>

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Current Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtCurrentPass" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger" ID="rqfCurrentPassword" ControlToValidate="txtCurrentPass"
                                        ErrorMessage="Enter Current Password">
                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password" ID="txtNewPassword"></asp:TextBox>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger" ID="rqfNewPassword" ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword"
                                        ErrorMessage="Required">
                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Password" ID="txtConfirmPassword"></asp:TextBox>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <h4>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger" ID="rqfConfirmPassword" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword"
                                        ErrorMessage="Required">
                                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </h4>
                                <h4>
                                    <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPassword" ControlToCompare="txtNewPassword" ID="PassCompare" ErrorMessage="Confirm password must match password" CssClass="label label-danger"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                </h4>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                                <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Change Password" ID="btnPasswordChange" OnClick="btnChangePassword_OnClick"></asp:Button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h4>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="label label-danger" ID="lblPassChange" Visible="False" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <%--Change User Password--%>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the C# Code for button Event:

```
protected void btnChangePassword_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //Changes Password of current Logged in User
    string oldPass = txtCurrentPass.Text;
    string newPass = txtNewPassword.Text;
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);

    if (txtCurrentPass.Text == txtNewPassword.Text)
    {
        lblPassChange.Visible = true;
        lblPassChange.Text = "Old Password must not match New Password";
    }
    else
    {
        if (user != null && user.ChangePassword(oldPass, newPass))
        {
            lblPassChange.Visible = true;
            lblPassChange.Text = "Password Changed Successfully";
            lblPassChange.CssClass = "label label-success";
        }
        else
        {
            lblPassChange.Visible = true;
            lblPassChange.Text = "Error, Please try again";
        }
    }
}
```

Where am i going wrong?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As a guess: Validation. If using tabs, you should have validators and buttons requiring validation have the same ValidationGroup. Otherwise validators that are not visible will prevent the form from submitting, yet the error will not be visible.

Comment: how would i go about implementing the validation group?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx

Comment: sounds like a bootstrap issue, but just to check, you say "within this tab pane there is a form." are you adding a form? if this is on a master page then that's a problem because there can only be one form on the page.

Comment: ValidationGroup attribute on the validators, has solved the problem, thanks for pointing me that direction.